# How to color keywords with HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm developing a SQL-based webapp and I need to color some keyworkds, such as SELECT, IN, UPDATE, DELETE, FROM, and so on, just like the Notepad++, Sublime, etc..

[image]

Does anybody have any idea on how to do that with javascript?

I was thinking about running an async task on every keystroke, but I have nooo idea on how to do that...

Comment: Have a look at code mirror http://codemirror.net/mode/sql/index.html. Probably you can use this.

Comment: You should definitely use a library like codemirror and others, however if you want to have some fun and roll your own solution, I had written a small proof of concept on how we could manipulate text on a page based on regular expressions http://jsfiddle.net/scarsick/tX4Ge/1/

Answer (score 3):

Per https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted add

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=sql"></script>
```

to your `<head>` and then put

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-sql">...</pre>
```

around your HTML-escaped SQL.

http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#sql_lang shows the SQL highlighting in action.

Comment: `?lang=sql` seems useless, Google returns the same script.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! It is a great resource when the text is static, but I was looking for something that could color while I'm writing..

Comment: @johnchen902, It returns the same script, and the script then loads lang-sql.js by inspection of its `src`.